# Issue with getting argument value form django rest framework url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django project that has an API view. The api view is associated with a url that accepts an argument in the url and a parameter after the ? in the parameters. I am trying to grab the argument that is located within the url which is `widget_id` to use it as a filter. I am running into an error.

view:

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        widget_id = self.kwargs.get('widget_id')
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id')
        user_widget = PersonWidgetDefinition.objects.all()\
            .filter(widget_definition_id=widget_id, person_id=user_id).count()
        if user_widget == 0:
            serializer = PersonWidgetDefinitionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if user_widget == 1:
            request.data.user_widget = True
            serializer = PersonWidgetDefinitionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

url:

```
    path('widgets/<int:widget_id>/user/', UserWidgetView.as_view(), name='user-widget'),
```

error:

```
TypeError at /api/v2/widgets/1/user/
put() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameters are passed as named parameters to the method (`get`, `post`, `put`, etc.):

```
def put(self, request, pk, widget_id, format=None):
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id')
        user_widget = PersonWidgetDefinition.objects.all()\
            .filter(widget_definition_id=widget_id, person_id=user_id).count()
        if user_widget == 0:
            serializer = PersonWidgetDefinitionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if user_widget == 1:
            request.data.user_widget = True
            serializer = PersonWidgetDefinitionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You however might want to check [generic views [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), and see if a certain generic view matches the needs of your view. Usually this can significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code.